# Homotopy with rational coefficients of simply connected manifolds that are not-rational homology spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have been reading a book on differential geometry/dynamical systems and this question comes from a fact used in a proof. The author says the following :

> Note first that $W$ is simply connected and closed and is not a rational homology sphere, then $n:=\dim W\geq 4$ and there exists $i_0\neq 0,1,n-1,n$ such that $b:=\dim H_i(W,\mathbb{Q})>0$ and $\dim H_i(W,\mathbb{Q})=0$ for $1\leq i<i_0$.

Now why is this the case ? I guess the part about $\dim W\geq 4$ could follow from the Poincare Conjecture but this seems a bit overkill. Now I don't know why the rest is true .

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a missing 0 suffix on the $i$ in $b:=\dim H_i(W,\mathbb{Q})>0$?

Comment: It should be **homology** with rational coefficients, not **homotopy**.

Answer (score 3):

As $W$ is simply connected, we have $H_1(W; \mathbb{Q}) \cong \pi_1(W)^{\text{ab}} = 0$. Moreover, since $W$ is closed and orientable, we have $H_{n-1}(W; \mathbb{Q}) \cong H^1(W; \mathbb{Q}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_1(W; \mathbb{Q}), \mathbb{Q}) = 0$ where the first isomorphism is given by Poincaré duality and the second follows from the universal coefficient theorem.

If $n = 3$, it would follow that $W$ is a rational homology sphere. Since $W$ is not a rational homology sphere, we see that $n \geq 4$ and $H_j(W; \mathbb{Q}) \neq 0$ for some $j \in \{2, \dots, n-2\}$ (we already know that $H_1(W; \mathbb{Q})$ and $H_{n-1}(W; \mathbb{Q})$ are zero). Let $i_0$ be the smallest such value of $j$. Then by definition, $H_{i_0}(W; \mathbb{Q}) \neq 0$ and $H_i(W; \mathbb{Q}) = 0$ for $1 \leq i < i_0$. As $H_{i_0}(W; \mathbb{Q})$ is a non-zero vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, we see that $b = \dim H_{i_0}(W; \mathbb{Q}) > 0$.